# I have tried everything with laravel and travisCI, it does not work

Tags: phpunit, laravel-5, travis-ci

I have tried everything because I want to use travisCI with laravel but it does not work at all.

My .travis.yml is:

```html
language: php
php:
  - 5
  - 5.2
  - 5.3
  - 5.5
  - 5.6
  - 7.0

before_script:
  - composer install --no-interaction

script:
- vendor/bin/phpunit
```

my phpunit.xml is:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit colors="true" bootstrap="bootstrap/autoload.php">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
            <directory>./tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

TravisCI always says: 
/home/travis/build.sh: line 57: vendor/bin/phpunit: Permission denied

I have deleted all the vendor folder and, created again with composer update, it does not work

I am using laravel 5.2.. and it runs very well in local but in travisci no.. what cold it be? what am i missing? Thanks! bythe way I put 777 permission etc etc and it does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as `phpunit` is the [default PHP test command on Travis](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/php/), have you tried just removing the `script:` step from your `.travis.yml` file to see what happens?

Also, the correct place for your `composer install` command is in the Travis `install` step, not the `before_script` step. I'm not sure if this matters, but it might be causing Composer to install the packages in a place where PHP can't find them.